# update multiple documents in elasticsearch?

Tags: javascript, elasticsearch

In my current code, I fetch multiple documents and update then one by one, as following:

```
results.hits.hits.forEach(function (hit) {
             hit._source.taskName = 'My-task-name';
             esClient.bulk({
                 body: [
                     {update: {_index: 'my-index', _type: 'default', _id: hit._id}},
                     {doc: hit._source}
                 ]
             }, function (err, resp) {
                 // ...
                 if (err) {
                     console.log(err);
                 }
                 if(resp) {
                     console.log(resp)
                 }
             });
         });
```

This approach has timeout issue.

So I want to update multiple documents in a single request. But I am not sure how to construct the body for it, send request asynchronously and then how to deal with the response. I would basically want to break up 'results' in chunks of, say 100 documents, and update a chunk in single request.

Comment: You are already using `esClient.bulk()`. you can just `[{update:...},{doc:..},{update:...},{doc:...}]`: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-bulk.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this instead, i.e. first create all the bulk commands and then invoke the `_bulk` endpoint:

```
const bulk = [];
results.hits.hits.forEach(function (hit) {
    hit._source.taskName = 'My-task-name';
    bulk.push({update: {_index: 'my-index', _type: 'default', _id: hit._id}});
    bulk.push({doc: hit._source});
});

esClient.bulk({
    body: bulk
}, function (err, resp) {
    // ...
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
    if(resp) {
        console.log(resp)
    }
});
```

Comment: bulk.push(
            {update: {_index: 'my-index', _type: 'default', _id: hit._id}},
            {doc: hit._source})
....would it be same?